# JIRA not recognizing dictionary object in cURL call

Tags: python, curl, dictionary, jira

This is the error I am currently getting while using the jira-python python module to automate some logging to JIRA.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/csd-user/test/libs/utils/butler.py", line 217, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/csd-user/test/libs/utils/butler.py", line 214, in main
    b.log_bug_exec(url)
  File "/home/csd-user/test/libs/utils/butler.py", line 47, in log_bug_exec
    cls.process_file(stdout)
  File "/home/csd-user/test/libs/utils/butler.py", line 108, in process_file
    cls.submit_bug(bug)
  File "/home/csd-user/test/libs/utils/butler.py", line 207, in submit_bug
    iss = cls.my_server.create_issue(fields=bug.json_dict['fields'])
  File "/opt/clearsky/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 706, in create_issue
    r = self._session.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))
  File "/opt/clearsky/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 81, in post
    return self.__verb('POST', url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/clearsky/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 74, in __verb
    raise_on_error(r, verb=verb, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/clearsky/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/utils.py", line 120, in raise_on_error
    r.status_code, error, r.url, request=request, response=r, **kwargs)
# This is the important part...
jira.utils.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400
    text: data was not an object
    url: https://jira.clearsky-data.net/rest/api/2/issue
```

My problem is that, as far as I can see, the dict object that I am passing it is perfectly valid.

```
    BUG FIELDS :: {'environment': 'node => 62-qa-driver12 (M3 - HA Only)\nversion => \nurl => https://jenkins.clearsky-data.net/job/BugLoggerTest/144/\ntimestamp => 2015-06-29_11-11-15\njob name => BugLoggerTest\nbuild number => 144\nversion number => Not present. Check git hash. Maybe add in processing of full failure list!\n', 'description': '', 'summary': 'Fill in Something', 'project': {'key': 'QABL'}, 'assignee': 'qa-auto', 'issuetype': {'name': 'Bug'}, 'priority': {'name': 'Major'}}


CLASS :: <type 'dict'>
```

Is formatted by this...

```
# creating JSON object (bug should not have to be changed after initialization)
        self.json_dict = ( {"fields": {
            "project": {'key': self.project},
            "issuetype": {'name': self.issue_type},
            "priority": {'name': self.priority},
            "assignee": self.assignee,
            "environment": self.environment,
            "description": self.description,
            "summary": self.summary } } )
```

This is the call to create the issue where the error is being thrown:

```
iss = cls.my_server.create_issue(fields=bug.json_dict['fields'])
# This calls a cURL POST or PUT command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignee is not what jira expects:

```
"assignee": self.assignee,
```

should read

```
"assignee": {'name': self.assignee}
```

I saw it in the [update example](http://jira.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

```
issue.update(summary='new summary', description='A new summary was added')
issue.update(assignee={'name': 'new_user'})
```